# Homeomorphism on a compact non-connected metric space

Tags: functional-analysis, general-topology, real-analysis

Let $X$ be disjoint union of a circle $C$, and an interval $I$.

Is it true that for every homeomorphism $f:X\to X$, $f(C)= C$ and $f(I)= I$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes: the connected components of $X$ are $C$ and $I$. So if $f:X\to X$ is a homeomorphism, it will map $I$ either onto itself, or onto $C$. But since $I$ and $C$ are not homemorphic ($I$ has the [fixed point property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283930/squaring-a-space-with-the-fixed-point-property), $C$ doesn't), the only option is that $f$ maps $C$ onto $C$ and $I$ onto $I$.